# Cookie Management Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get all cookies info while doing web crawling for a site. I have written this code so far

```
Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
```

I only get one cookie (which is HTTP checked/enabled) but when I inspect the site it has multiple cookies. See below

[image]

Is there any method to get all cookies while doing web-scraping ?

**EDIT:**

Here is the coding making the `request` using `lastResponse` to set the cookie.

```
public static Connection makeRequest(UrlProperty urlProperty) {

        Response lastResponse = urlProperty.getReponse();

        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(urlProperty.getName());

        connection.userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT);
        connection.timeout(Constants.TIME_OUT);

        if(lastResponse != null) {
            Map<String, String> cookies = lastResponse.cookies();

            connection.cookies(cookies);

            String cookieString = "";

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
                cookieString = cookie.getKey() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; ";
            }

            if(!cookieString.isEmpty()) {
                connection.request().header("Cookie", cookieString);
            }
        }

        return connection;

    }
```

P.S. I am using *Jsoup* Request and Response.

Comment: could you provide the code you are using for sending request including the request header ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I have uploaded the code.